# PHP Include Is Giving Me Errors When I Use Direct Link

Tags: php, file, hyperlink, get, include

I am trying to include a php file using php `include`, and the catch is that I need to use variables in the URL...  I know that I cannot do this with a relative link, so I am using the direct link but getting this error: [image: Image Of The Error]

I was wondering if anybody could tell me what I am doing wrong...

**Here is the `include` code:**

```
<?php

include 'http://www.procapturemarketing.net/Scripts/PCMSSystemsOwned.php?ref=NMVT';

?>
```

**And Here is PCMSSYSTEMSOWNED.php:**

```
<?php

$systems = explode(', ',$row_rsUsers['Systems']);

if (in_array("Empower", $systems) and $_GET['ref'] != "Empower") { ?>

<li onclick="location.href='nmvt/Home.php';" class="nmvtli"><a href="nmvt/Home.php">Empower System</a></li>

<?php } if (in_array("MCA", $systems) and $_GET['ref'] != "MCA") { ?>

<li onclick="location.href='nmvt/Home.php';" class="nmvtli"><a href="nmvt/Home.php">MCA System</a></li>

<?php } if (in_array("Neucopia", $systems) and $_GET['ref'] != "Neucopia") { ?>

<li onclick="location.href='nmvt/Home.php';" class="nmvtli"><a href="nmvt/Home.php">Neucopia System</a></li>

<?php } if (in_array("NMVT", $systems) and $_GET['ref'] != "NMVT") { ?>

<li onclick="location.href='nmvt/Home.php';" class="nmvtli"><a href="nmvt/Home.php">NMVT System</a></li>

<?php } ?>
```

**Also if you need it here is the recordset `rsUsers`:**

```
$colname_rsUsers = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_rsUsers = $_GET['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
$query_rsUsers = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsUsers, "text"));
$rsUsers = mysql_query($query_rsUsers, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsUsers = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsUsers);
```

Comment: I left everything that was possibly causing the problem

Comment: Well, PHP clearly tells you what's wrong: you're trying to include remote files when you're not allowed to (the corresponding `ini` rule is disabled). So either enable it, or, better, think why do you need this at all.

Comment: My .ini file isnt making it work, i updated the allow_url_fopen and didnt work

Comment: I also used `ini_set(allow_url_fopen, true);
ini_set(allow_url_include, true);` in the php document but that didnt work either